# Duplicate symbol for archtecture x86

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

I am using mailcore framework and i am getting an error saying "Duplicate symbol for archtecture x86" as well 'directory not found for option'

Below is the error log.

> Ld
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DummyApp.app/DummyApp
>   normal x86_64
>       cd "/Users/user/Desktop/Desktop/Working Folder/Current Apps /Get Capture It/DummyApp/DummyApp"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -L/Users/user/EmailClient/MailCore/iOSPorts/ports/security/openssl/build/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Intermediates/DummyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DummyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DummyApp.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.1 /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libsasl2.a
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libmailcore.a
>   -lz -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework Security -framework QuickLook -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -liconv -framework
>   AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox
>   -framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreFoundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit
>   /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libsqlcipher.a
>   -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Intermediates/DummyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DummyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DummyApp_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DummyApp.app/DummyApp
>
> ld: warning: directory not found for option
>   '-L/Users/user/EmailClient/MailCore/iOSPorts/ports/security/openssl/build/Debug-iphoneos'
>   duplicate symbol _main in:
>       /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Intermediates/DummyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DummyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fmdb.o
>       /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Intermediates/DummyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DummyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main-FFC4D805A2793675.o
>   duplicate symbol _main in:
>       /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Intermediates/DummyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DummyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/fmdb.o
>       /Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DummyApp-chqcfanqqojjezfzonmnrjqnlsuy/Build/Intermediates/DummyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DummyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/main-6E64576BC394526D.o
>   ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate symbol error is exactly what it states, which is a duplicate symbol `main` in both:

```
fmdb
```

and

```
main
```

The other error is because the compiler can't find:

```
/Users/user/EmailClient/MailCore/iOSPorts/ports/security/openssl/build/Debug-iphoneos
```

Comment: Actually i got the problem after posting the question. Really easy to fix.